# Okta API and Agent questions

Tags: api, okta

We're building a IaaS platform for the media industry.  We're just looking to verify a few areas of Okta's capabilities and how to manage.

- Okta is a web application for performing system administrative tasks against Active Directory repositories

  - Does Okta have such web application?
  - A demonstration of the web application
  - Is it possible to have a trial copy?
- Authentication & Authorization via corporate AD

  - How do we set up the Okta AD Agent?
  - How do we use Okta API (to be integrated with our platform) to perform authentication against a corporate AD?
  - How do we use Okta API (to be integrated with our platform) to retrieve custom attribute information from corporate AD?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your questions. Here are some resources to help answer your questions:

Our website has detailed documentation on how Okta works with Active Directory. 
https://www.okta.com/resources/datasheet-ad-integration/

How to set up AD in Okta: https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/Okta-AD-Agent?_ga=1.41164711.449313748.1470873855

Furthermore, you can find further information on how to use the API on on our Developer helpsite: developer.okta.com